# Should you make up for left-out prayers?

Tags: salat-qada

If I was unable to pray because of physical condition. should I make up for all the prayers?

Specifically, I was having only water as food for 2-3 day and was feeling so exhausted what all I could do is lay down on, and it was hard to even stand up. I am in my teen years, I am not sure if younger/older people would have it better or worse.

Please provide a detailed answer.

Comment: This is different question @Medi1Saif. Totally different case i think.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal the ruling or answer isn't different and that's why it is a duplicate!

Comment: Question is not same, and until or unless someone is unconscious, he has to make his prayers... and in question, he was not unconscious.

Answer (score 0):

As you know praying 5 times a day is obligatory for all muslims(women get a few days off per month). Now, this is not that case in which you were unconscious, which is a special case for men.

**You had your nerves and you had to pray, ideally you were supposed to just make prayer in your mind! if you could not move any part of your body.**
 If you could move your hands, than you just mimic as much as can in that position(that too if doctors allow you to move your hands).
**As a general rule of thumb, in any medical condition, we are supposed to be as close to the proper praying method as we can. Like if we can sit, we will still stand up, and will sit only when going for sajdah etc. If we can't stand, we will sit and will try to do proper sajdah if we can. Getting as close as possible without hurting yourself is the key.**

Without being unconscious, we are not allowed to leave our obligatory prayers. If a man goes unconscious, prayers in that period of unconsciousness are waived and he does not need to make them up later when he wakes up.

So, you should make up your Missed prayers now.

Here is a [good reading](https://islamqa.info/en/72216) on the topic.

### واللہ اعلم